# sum multiple columns of same table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I am working on developing sports site.

In this site I've two tables one is `tbl_team` which stores the team details and another table is `tbl_tournamentmatches` which stores the details of different rounds of tournament matches.

In my `tbl_tournamentmatches` I'm storing `team1_id`, `team2_id`, `team1_score` and `team2_score`.

My Table having entry like this:

**tbl_tournamentmatches**

```
match_id team1_id team2_id team1_score team2_score
5        4        9        15          5
6        9        16       15          5
7        4        16       5          15
8        4        16       5          15
```

**tbl_team**

```
team_id team_title
4       KKR
9       RR
16      CSK
```

I want Result Should look like this:-

```
Team name Score
CSK        35
KKR        25
RR         20
```

I'd used this query :-

```
select * from 
(
   SELECT sum(team1_points) as totalpoints,t.team_title 
   from tbl_team t 
   left join tbl_tournamentmatches m 
   on t.team_id = m.team1_id 
   where tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36 
   group by team1_id 
   union 
   SELECT sum(team2_points) as totalpoints,t.team_title 
   from tbl_team t 
   left join tbl_tournamentmatches m 
   on t.team_id = m.team2_id 
   where tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36 
   group by team2_id
) s
```

But i got result like this :-

```
KKR   25
RR    15
RR     5
CSK   35
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: RR is in both the team..team1_id and team2_id ?

Comment: yes it is in both the fields

Comment: You could have give a `match_id` in the first table.

Comment: i didn't understand what u r trying to tell

Comment: Is there a `id` column in `tbl_tournamentmatches` table??

Comment: Then please that too in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90510/discussion-between-tani-partner-and-ullas).

Comment: Added. Please help me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: remove the second union and change the join condition to `on ( t.team_id = m.team1_id or t.team_id = m.team2_id )`. change the sum like `sum(case when t.team_id = m.team1_id then m.team1_points else m.team2_points)`. note that i cant replicate this as i dont have your ddl ( eg. where is tournament_id in your ddl )

Comment: Thanks for your reply @amdixon but kickstart users solution helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the joins to get the team and points for each match, and then do the sum on the results of that:-

```
SELECT team_title, sum(team_points) as totalpoints 
FROM 
(
   SELECT team1_id AS team_id, team1_points AS team_points, t.team_title 
   FROM tbl_team t 
   LEFT JOIN tbl_tournamentmatches m 
   ON t.team_id = m.team1_id 
   WHERE tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT team2_id AS team_id, team2_points AS team_points, t.team_title 
   FROM tbl_team t 
   LEFT JOIN tbl_tournamentmatches m 
   ON t.team_id = m.team2_id 
   WHERE tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36 
) s
GROUP BY team_id, team_title
```

Comment: Thanks Very much for your help. This solution solved my problem and i m accepting this as answer. Thanks again dude

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT t.team_name
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.team_id = tn.team1_id THEN tn.team1_score
        WHEN t.team_id = tn.team2_id THEN tn.team2_score
    END) AS score
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN tournament tn ON t.team_id = tn.team1_id OR t.team_id = team2_id
GROUP BY t.team_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Union all` to make all team and score as different rows.
Then use an `Inner Join`.

**Query**

```
select t2.team_title as TeamName, 
sum(team_score) as Score 
from 
( 
    select match_id,team1_id as team_id, team1_score as team_score 
    from tblMatch 
    union all 
    select match_id,team2_id as team_id, team2_score as team_score 
    from tblMatch 
)t1 
join tblTeam t2 
on t1.team_id = t2.team_id 
group by t2.team_id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d55b7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it.

In your query I see fields that you don't include in your table (e.g. agegroup_id), but you only are a step of a solution: change your outter *"select * from "* for a: *"select sum(totalpoints), team_title"* and add a group by at the end: "*group by team_title*"

```
select sum(totalpoints) as totalpoints, team_title from  
(    
    SELECT sum(team1_score) as totalpoints, t.team_title     
    from tbl_team t     
    join tbl_tournamentmatches m
      on t.team_id = m.team1_id     
    --where tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36     
    group by team1_id     
    union     
    SELECT sum(team2_score) as totalpoints, t.team_title     
    from tbl_team t     
    join tbl_tournamentmatches m 
      on t.team_id = m.team2_id     
    --where tournament_id = 3 AND agegroup_id = 36     
    group by team2_id 
) s 
group by team_title;
```